# UITableView reloaddata problem when having a MKMapview in a tableview cell

Tags: iphone, uitableview, mkmapview, reloaddata

I am writing an app can load data from from web, then put the data in a grouped uitableview, where I put data in the first section, and meantime, I want to plot these data on a mapview in the second section of table.

I managed to implement these in the tableview, and it works fine. Then I add a refresh button on the navigation bar, so if someone press the refresh button, the app will fetch data from web again and reload the tableview with the new data.

Here comes the problem, when I refresh the data and call the method reloaddata, all table cells in both section get refreshed, I mean, the map is re-loaded and animated zoom in from world map to the interest region every time I press the refresh button. But I only want re-plot the annotations based on the refreshed data, not the map.

I think the problem come from the call of
    [self.tableView reloadData] 
method. Is there a way just to reload data for the first section rather than all sections in a grouped tableview?

Any suggestion or comment is appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Could you post some code on how you refresh the data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `- reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:` (in the [UITableView Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html)) to do just that.  You will just need to create an NSArray of the index path/paths of the row/rows you want to update and it will reload just those